# VIM: Delete+Paste in one "command"?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm doing a lot of text manipulation between multiple files that requires a lot of `yy`, `dd` and `p`ing. This may sound crazy but is there some shorter way of doing `dd` and `p` in one go? Maybe even with a plugin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just make a map:

```
:map J ddp
```

and then <kbd>J</kbd> (or whatever you want) will do the combined operation.

Incidentally, I always map <kbd>D</kbd> to `dd`, since I delete entire lines much more often than to the end of the line. That makes it easy to use <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to do your task.

Comment: I deleted my answer because Peter's is the much better answer. +1!

Comment: nice tip.  How did you markup the key presses?  I don't see "key" or "kbd" in the help... Or can I just do <kbd>?</kbd>  I may have just answered my own question! :)

Comment: heh heh. yes, you use the <kbd> tags.

Comment: careful with mapping over the "J" key, because by default that joins lines together (which personally I find very useful)

Comment: Nice, time to wrap it in .vimrc :)

Comment: I personally have control-j/k :nnoremap <c-j> ddp ... :nnoremap <c-k> ddkP . for both up and down. J is really handy and I dont recommend remapping it either. <c-k> isn't mapped and <c-j> isnt particularily useful

Comment: just for reference, I picked `J` as an example only, and meant to pick `K` anyway (I've remapped `K` for something else, since the default function isn't very useful on `K`; I couldn't remember whether I'd used `J` or `K`).

Answer (score 6):

I typically just use:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (selects the whole line)

and then

<kbd>p</kbd> (pastes over the selected line with your current register)

Answer (score 1):

I just had a go at expanding peter's answer to include a visualline mapping so you can do multiple lines at once. I personally prefer <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> / <kbd>k</kbd> but you can do whatever you like. Enjoy.

```
nnoremap <c-j> ddp
nnoremap <c-k> ddkP
vnoremap <c-j> dp'[V']
vnoremap <c-k> dkP'[V']
```